# Django orm queries with left varaible is not certain

Tags: python, django

I want to make a query like this:

```
Student.objects.filter(id= id).update(name=value)
```

And the value comes from the user.

But the problem is that I'm not only to update name but also update some
other information like address or phone number. I don't want to create duplicated codes
like:

```
Student.objects.filter(id= id).update(address=value)        
Student.objects.filter(id= id).update(phone_number=value)
```

I only want to have one line code like:

```
Student.objects.filter(id= id).update(XXX=XXX_value)
```

So I wonder if I can assign any variable to the left varaible inside update function
or not.

Sorry, the left key is not a certain value. It depends on the user's post.
It might be an address or just name next time. It's not a fixed value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically define the fields by providing them in a dictionary and using `**` to unpack the dictionary into arguments for `update()`.

```
fields_to_update = {
    "address": address_value,
    "phone_number": phonenumber_value,
}
Students.objects.filter(id=update_id).update(**fields_to_update)
```

Comment: Excellent. That's what I want. How do you find this solution? Does the documents say anything about this? thanks.

Comment: No, the documents don't say anything about this.  It's a feature of python, and not specific to django.

Answer (score 1):

As per [update docs](https://You%20can%20update%20multiple%20fields%20%E2%80%94%20there%E2%80%99s%20no%20limit%20on%20how%20many)

> You can update multiple fields — there’s no limit on how many

So the following should do

```
Student.objects.filter(id=id).update(address=address_value, phone_number=phone_number_value)
```

**EDIT**

> left variable is not a fixed item. It could be address or just be phone_number

In that case populate a dict dynamically and then unpack it in `update()`. See an example below (your conditions may be of course different).

```
fields_to_update = {}

if address_value:
    fields_to_update["address"] = address_value

if phone_number_value:
    fields_to_update["phone_number"] = phone_number_value

Student.objects.filter(id=id).update(**fields_to_update)
```

Another alternative is to not use `update()` but to work with a `Student` instance directly.

```
student = Student.objects.get(id=id)

if address_value:
    student.address = address_value

if phone_number_value:
    student.phone_number = phone_number_value

student.save()
```

Be aware that `student = Student.objects.get(id=id)` can raise `DoesNotExist` if a student with the given id is not found.

Comment: Sorry the left variable is not a fixed item. It could be address or just be phone_number.

Comment: You mean the fields to update aren't fixed?

Comment: Sorry I don't want to use if else. The accepted answer is what I want. Also thanks for your contribution. :)